# Multiple Splide Sliders with Progress bars "null property style"

Tags: javascript, jquery, splidejs

I'm attempting to have 2 Splide sliders on a page with progress bars, using the documentation that have provided im able to have both of them working fine but for some reason the second progress bar throws an error each time saying the width value is null, when it is set as 0 in the css as per the documentations reqiuirements. Other slider works fine even when the second one is throwing an error and they're not conflicting as far as I've tested.

The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`

Below is my Code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var splide = new Splide( '#insights-slider', {
        perPage: 3,
        perMove: 1,
        pagination: false,
        arrows : false,
        breakpoints: {
            768: {
                perPage: 1,
            },
        }
    });

    var testimonialSplide = new Splide( '#testimonial-splide', {
        perPage: 1,
        perMove: 1,
        pagination: false,
        arrows : false,
        type: 'loop',
        autoplay: true,
        breakpoints: {
            768: {
                perPage: 1,
            },
        }
    });

    var bar = splide.root.querySelector( '.my-slider-progress-bar' );
    var testimonialBar = testimonialSplide.root.querySelector( '.testimonial-slider-progress-bar' );

    splide.on( 'mounted move', function () {
        var end = splide.Components.Controller.getEnd() + 1;
        bar.style.width = String( 100 * ( splide.index + 1 ) / end ) + '%';
    });

    testimonialSplide.on( 'mounted move', function () {
        var end = testimonialSplide.Components.Controller.getEnd() + 1;
        testimonialBar.style.width = String( 100 * ( testimonialSplide.index + 1 ) / end ) + '%';
    });

    splide.mount();
    testimonialSplide.mount();
});
```

```css
.testimonial-slider-progress {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,1);
    width: 100%;
}

.testimonial-slider-progress-bar {
    background: white;
    height: 3px;
    transition: width 1000ms ease;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="relative lg:py-32 md:py-24 sm:py-16 py-8 lg:px-36 md:px-8 px-4 bg-purple-th">
    <div class="relative w-full splide" id="testimonial-splide">
        <div class="splide__track">
            <ul class="splide__list">
            <?php
                while(have_rows('testimonials')) : the_row();
                    $testimonial = get_sub_field('testimonial');
                    $name = get_sub_field('name');
                    $company = get_sub_field('company');
                    $job_title = get_sub_field('job_title');
            ?>
            <div class="splide__slide relative w-full text-center lg:pt-16 pt-8 lg:px-36 md:px-24 px-4">
                <svg width="41" height="27" style="transform: translateX(-50%);" viewBox="0 0 41 27" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="absolute top-0 left-1/2">
                    <path d="M17.2233 18.9599C17.2233 11.8199 9.67532 9.6779 5.39132 13.2479C5.69732 6.82189 9.47132 3.45589 15.5913 3.45589V0.191895C7.43132 0.191895 0.90332 5.3939 0.90332 16.8179C0.90332 22.4279 4.16732 26.3039 9.06332 26.3039C13.8573 26.3039 17.2233 22.8359 17.2233 18.9599ZM40.0713 18.9599C40.0713 11.8199 32.5233 9.6779 28.2393 13.2479C28.5453 6.82189 32.3193 3.45589 38.4393 3.45589V0.191895C30.2793 0.191895 23.7513 5.3939 23.7513 16.8179C23.7513 22.4279 27.0153 26.3039 31.9113 26.3039C36.7053 26.3039 40.0713 22.8359 40.0713 18.9599Z" fill="white"/>
                </svg>
                <p class="text-2xl lg:w-1/2 mx-auto md:w-3/4 w-full"><?php echo $testimonial ?></p>
                <p class="mb-0 mt-8 text-white"><?= $name ?>, <?= $company ?> - <?= $job_title ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial-slider-progress">
        <div class="testimonial-slider-progress-bar"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You're HTML has no a  div  with class `.my-slider-progress-bar` - hence you can't select or style anything

Comment: that is for the other slider, that on works fine